# How do I connect to a RESTlet webservice built in Eclipse from an Android app built in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

So, for school I have to create an android app, using Android Studio, that interacts with a RESTful web service. I have to create a program in Eclipse using Java to set up a RESTlet web service on my localhost. And then use Android studio to create an app to interact with that web service. In my Eclipse web service, I extract data from the KNMI (weather institute). I have to display that data in my Android app.

I am utterly stuck. I tried asking my teacher for help several times (it’s only intranet contact and takes at least a week to get a response) but no luck. Since I get most of my help from StackOverflow and looking at other people’s problems and learning from them, I thought for the first time I’d ask you guys directly, as I couldn’t find the solution to my specific problem here. I’ve tried many different codes and been at this for weeks.

I used the following to set up the web service:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Post;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class FirstServerResource extends ServerResource {

    private final static String POST_PARAMS = "vars=TN:TX&stns=260";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182  
        new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, FirstServerResource.class).start();
    }

    @Get
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegevens/getdata_dag.cgi");

            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            if (urlConn != null)
                urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
            if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {
                in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
                        Charset.defaultCharset());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    int cp;
                    while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char) cp);
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL: " + "http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegevens/getdata_dag.cgi", e);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Post
    public String PostData() {

        return "test";
    }
}
```

This code works for me and returns the following on my localhost:8182 =

```
# BRON: KONINKLIJK NEDERLANDS METEOROLOGISCH INSTITUUT (KNMI)
# Opmerking: door stationsverplaatsingen en veranderingen in waarneemmethodieken zijn deze tijdreeksen van dagwaarden mogelijk inhomogeen! Dat betekent dat deze reeks van gemeten waarden niet geschikt is voor trendanalyse. Voor studies naar klimaatverandering verwijzen we naar de gehomogeniseerde reeks maandtemperaturen van De Bilt <http://www.knmi.nl/kennis-en-datacentrum/achtergrond/gehomogeniseerde-reeks-maandtemperaturen-de-bilt> of de Centraal Nederland Temperatuur <http://www.knmi.nl/kennis-en-datacentrum/achtergrond/centraal-nederland-temperatuur-cnt>.
# 
# 
# STN      LON(east)   LAT(north)     ALT(m)  NAME
# 260:         5.180       52.100       1.90  DE BILT
# 
# YYYYMMDD = Date (YYYY=year MM=month DD=day); 
# TN       = Minimum temperature (in 0.1 degrees Celsius); 
# TX       = Maximum temperature (in 0.1 degrees Celsius); 
# 
# STN,YYYYMMDD,   TN,   TX
# 
  260,20181101,   85,  132
  260,20181102,   23,  118
  260,20181103,   -1,  101
  260,20181104,    6,  119
  260,20181105,   51,  112
  260,20181106,   68,  190
  260,20181107,   87,  139
  260,20181108,   40,  137
  260,20181109,   58,  112
  260,20181110,   93,  134
  260,20181111,   82,  134
  260,20181112,   85,  117
  260,20181113,   81,  132
  260,20181114,   38,  132
  260,20181115,   31,  128
  260,20181116,    6,   77
  260,20181117,   10,   91
  260,20181118,  -14,   78
  260,20181119,   28,   69
  260,20181120,   26,   44
  260,20181121,   18,   53
  260,20181122,   17,   43
  260,20181123,   -8,   69
  260,20181124,    6,   35
  260,20181125,   19,   47
  260,20181126,   35,   60
  260,20181127,   14,   52
  260,20181128,   28,   95
  260,20181129,   95,  112
  260,20181130,   63,  116
  260,20181201,   57,   96
  260,20181202,   96,  132
  260,20181203,   74,  133
  260,20181204,    2,   96
  260,20181205,   17,   84
  260,20181206,   84,  123
  260,20181207,   71,  118
  260,20181208,   67,  112
  260,20181209,   55,  100
  260,20181210,   36,   77
  260,20181211,   -9,   77
  260,20181212,  -29,   43
  260,20181213,   -8,   25
  260,20181214,   -8,   33
  260,20181215,  -11,    8
  260,20181216,  -10,   33
  260,20181217,   24,   84
  260,20181218,   44,   79
  260,20181219,   55,   98
  260,20181220,   54,   87
```

Now I have to extract this String data from the localhost.

My study book (note: my study book is very outdated) says I have to do the following to retrieve information from a webservice:

- Add the following to build.gradle:

  ```
  dependencies {
      ...
      compile group: 'org.restlet.android', name: 'org.restlet', version: '2.3.6'
  }

  repositories {
      maven {
          mavenCentral ()
          url 'http://maven.restlet.com/'
      }
  }
  ```

  Configuration ‘compile’ is now obsolete, so I replaced it with ‘implementation’.
- Use the code:

  ```
  package com.example.restful;

  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import org.json.JSONTokener;
  import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
  import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      public static final String URL = "http://ipadress:8182/";
      public static final String TAG = "RESTlet App";

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(URL);

          try {
              Representation r = cr.get();
              String json = r.getText();

              Log.i(TAG, "Received get reply: " + r.toString());

              JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(text).nextValue();

              if (object != null) {
                  MyClass mine = new MyClass();
                  mine.text = object.getString("text");
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get: " + e.getMessage());
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  and

  ```
  package com.example.restful;

  public class MyClass {
      public String mine = null;
      public MyClass() {};
      public MyClass(String mine) {
          this.mine = mine;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "text = " + mine;
      }
  }
  ```

But I cannot get this to compile. It reads: “cannot resolve symbol ‘text’”. 
Personally, I felt that this code was wrong and that I don’t need to use JSON, because it’s String data.

So I tried:

```
package com.example.restletclient;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.restlet.Request;
import org.restlet.data.Form;
import org.restlet.data.Method;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://restlet.com");
        Request request = new Request(Method.GET, "http://ipadress:8182");
        clientResource.setRequest(request);

        Form form = new Form();
        form.set("foo" ,"barValue");

        try {
            Representation response = clientResource.post(form.getWebRepresentation(null));
            System.out.println("Got response! response: " + response.getText());
            textView.setText(new ClientResource("ipadress:8182").get().getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No response. Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

com.example.restletclient I/System.out: No response. Error: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

I went to my ipadress:8182 on the Android emulator and I could see the webservice page. So I know the connection is good. But I don’t understand the error shown.

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong? 
Am I on the right track or is there a different code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's too much provided here. You mentioned a compile error--is that the main problem?

Comment: Well I guess the main problem is that I don't know the correct way to get String data from a restlet web service. But if you'd have to solve one of my errors, than I'd focus on the latter: Internal Connector Error (1002).